# How to convert a file containing a list of lists to a string?

Tags: python, list

I have a text file with the following content

```
[['server', ' working'], ['android', ' working'], ['using', ' could']]
```

From this .txt file I want to ouput another .txt file with content

```
server, working

android, working

using, cloud
```

with an empty line between them. 
I have tried this

```
        text_file = 'str_arr.txt'
        with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
            myNames = f.readlines()
        output = ""
        for word in myNames:
            for characters in word:
                output += characters +","
            output = output[:-1] + "\n"
        print(output)
```

And it's output is

```
[,[,'s','e','r','v','e','r'],..],]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem ?

Comment: You will understand your own code better if you don't name the variables `i` and `j`. If you expect it to be a _word_, name it `word`; if you expect it to be a character, name it `character`. Then see if the code still makes sense and debug to see whether the variables really hold what they should. FYI: `i` and `j` are in fact common variable names (not so much in Python) and when they are used, they are always integers.

Comment: @zvone nice comments I edited the question as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ast` & `join`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

lst = literal_eval("""[['server', ' working'], ['android', ' working'], ['using', ' could']]""")

out = "\n\n".join(
    ", ".join(x for x in sublst)
    for sublst in lst)
print(out)
```

This yields

```
server,  working

android,  working

using,  could
```

For your purpose, you'd need to get the file content as well:

```
with open("your_file", "r") as fp:
    lst = literal_eval(fp.read())
    # or fp.readlines()
    ...
```